# Делаю XML парсинг AQuery + Ajax. Есть проблемы с изображениями, которые частично не отображаются

Tags: android, ajax, xml

Делаю XML парсинг AQuery + Ajax. Есть проблемы с изображениями, которые частично не отображаются. Гонял де багером. Всегда на входе description (кусок текста) с тегом img и атрибутом scr и ссылкой на изображение, но в одном случае он ее выдирает, а в другом нет. Куда рыть?.

```
                String src = null;
            try {
                src = new XmlDom("<xml>"+description+"</xml>").tag("img").attr("src");
                if (src.startsWith("//") ) {
                    src = "http:"+src;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            item.setImg(src);
```

Comment: Пример случая, когда забирает, а когда нет, можете приветси?

Comment: Не тянет:
<description>
<![CDATA[
Goldman Sachs признал ошибочным прогноз 2013 года, когда рекомендовал продавать акции Microsoft. Инвестиционный банк повысил рейтинг акций компании с пункта «продать» до «нейтрального» уровня. С 4 ноября 2013 года котировки акций Microsoft выросли на 84%. <img src="https://static49.siliconrus.cmtt.ru/paper-preview-fox/s/ac/sachs-microsoft/2b8f6c828a17-original.jpg">
]]>
</description>

Comment: так у вас же `<img>` внитри `CDATA`, он же не будет распознан, как тег.

Comment: Что делать с CDATA?

Comment: Сделал так, хотя малая часть ссылок не выдирается:     description = description.replace(".png\">",".png\"/>").replace(".jpg\">",".jpg\"/>")